# Can someone please explain the process behind this code please? Finding the smallest number in an arrayList

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

As a complete beginner, I'm trying to understand the outcome of this code. What confuses me is:
 
`if (minAge > people[i].age) {
        minAge = people[i].age;
        youngestPersonsName = people[i].name;`

How I'm understanding this, is that if John:31 is greater than Joseph:30 (True statement), then John:31 is assigned to minAge ??

In my head, John is the outcome due to his age > than the rest!

```
var people = [
    {
        name: "John",
        age: 31
    },
    {
        name: "Joseph",
        age: 30
    },
    {
        name: "Mary",
        age: 19
    }
];

var youngestPersonsName = people[0].name;
var minAge = people[0].age;

for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (minAge > people[i].age) {
        minAge = people[i].age;
        youngestPersonsName = people[i].name;
    }
}

console.log("The youngest person is" + youngestPersonsName);
```

Comment: `John is the outcome due to his age > than the rest!`  Eh!?, your looking for the min age, so in my head it's Mary..  It might help you more if you alter your comparison to ->  `people[i].age < minAge`...

Comment: Your code is looking for eldest person not the youngest one, which is complete contrast to what your question heading is

Comment: @Keith Yes!!!! Thank you Kieth. That's way more intuitive to understand!

Answer (score 0):

the algorithm just loops over all the entries, checking if the global minAge is greater than the current item of the loop (meaning that the looped item is younger than the global minAge).  if this is the case the minAge is replaced by that element... at the end of the loop Mary should be the outcome.  In your case the loop starting at index 0 is of no use since you already assigned it as youngest. before the loop.

Comment: That actually makes sense! Thank you :)